# How to pass implicit value from one template layout to another in Play Framework's Twirl?

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

let's say I have this controller's Action:

```
def getPost = Action { implicit request => Ok(views.html.post("bla bla bla")) }
```

Now I have two layouts:

```
// baseLayout.scala.html:
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit req: RequestHeader)
<html>
  ...
  @content
  ...
</html>
```

And

```
// postLayout.scala.html:
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit req: RequestHeader)
@baseLayout(title) { // Error: Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here
  <h1>Post</h1>
  @content
}
```

then I have this template:

```
// post.scala.html
@(post: String)(implicit req: RequestHeader)
@postLayout("First post") {
  <div>@post</div>
}
```

This code does not compile. I get this error

```
Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here (See up)
```

It is like the implicit `RequestHeader` is successfully transmitted:
from the `Action` to the `post` template,
then from the `post` template to `postLayout` template.

But it is not transmitted from the `postLayout` template to the `baseLayout` template.

I am suspecting that it is due to the fact that in `postLayout` template, the implicit comes after the `Html` block, it might discard any implicit propagation. Apart from that I don't see any explication, I am completely lost.

Comment: What happens if you use the req explicitly, like: `@baseLayout(title){ ...}(req)`?! You might want to have a look at the generated Scala files somewhere in `target/scala-2.1*/...`.

Comment: I have Error: `req is not defined`. Really bizarre, I can use the implicit req in postLayout, but if I try to pass it to baseLayout, I have a `req is not defined`. I even tried to define baseLayout like this: `@(title: String, req: RequestHeader)(content: Html)` , so I can call it like this: `baseLayout(title, req){...}`,  still req is not defined.

Comment: I will check the generated Scala files ...

Comment: BTW, which Play version are you using? Just because, your example code works fine for me with 2.7.3.